# Download xlsx via Axios working in Chrome, but not in FF

Tags: node.js, express, axios, xlsx

I have a xlsx file which I would like to serve via node-express. Up to the point where the result is received by the browser everything seems to be ok; the file can be opened from Chrome and saved in Firefox. The problem is that I **can not open the file when Firefox asks whether to open or save the file**. If the file is opened (from FF whithout prior save) it will trigger an

> Excel can not open file ... because the file format or file extension is not valid...

What am I missing?

Express:

```
exports.download = async (req, res) => {
  const path = require('path');
  const file = 'test.xlsx';
  let myPath = path.join(__dirname, file);

  await res.download(myPath, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

The Axios-request is

```
const download = async () => {
  let myRes = await http({
    method: 'get',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    url: `${http.defaults.baseUrl}/download`,
  });

  return myRes;
};
```